# Elastic phrase_prefix does not work if there is a number in middle of query

Tags: elasticsearch

On my project I have used `phrase_prefix` for textbox search, everything works perfectly, except the case the query contain the number in the middle, for example, searching `M2M` does not work at all:

My query DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "M2",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If searching with `M2`, I got four documents with title contains `M2M`. But if searching `M2M`, I got nothing, my expectation would be the same result with `M2`.

Is there anyone please suggest how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I have figured out why the bug happens, since [word delimiter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter) has option: `split_on_numerics` defaults to `true`. It should be `false`.